# Add object name in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have created a lightning component which displays records based on searching a text (through custom search). This gives me the list of records along with the field names which I have mentioned in the code. I need to create 3 columns with one column to give the name of the object of the found records.  Like if I have a list of searched records say 1,2,3, the corresponding record should also have the object name.

Please help me with the code to get the object name in one of the 3 columns. Here is the code snippet with Line 13 and 14 as the displaying fields.:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="COMPACT"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"  />
<!-- Display a header with details about the record -->
<div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">        
  <p class="slds-text-heading--label">{!v.simpleRecord.Name}</p>        
  <p class="slds-text-heading--label">{!v.simpleRecord.CreatedDate}</p>          
  <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right--small  slds-truncate slds-align-left"><a href="{! $Site.siteUrlPrefix + '/detail/' + v.simpleRecord.Id}">Go to details</a></h1>
</div>
<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
  <div class="recordError">
    <ui:message title="Error" severity="error" closable="true">
      {!v.recordError}
    </ui:message>
  </div>
</aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Also attaching the code snippet of the related search list:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute type="list" name="recordIds" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<h1>Search Results</h1>           
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recordIds}" var="id">        
  <c:customSearchResultItem recordId="{!id}"/>        
</aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Controller-

```
public class CustomSearchController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> searchForIds(String searchText) {
List<List<SObject>> results = [FIND :searchText IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 10), Contact(Id), Lead(Id)]; 
List<String> ids = new List<String>();
for (List<SObject> sobjs : results) {
  for (SObject sobj : sobjs) {
    ids.add(sobj.Id);
  }
}
return ids;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code for your controller as it takes `recordId` and figure outs the Object Type by checking into the prefix of the `recordID`.

Hope this solves ur purpose.

```
 @AuraEnabled   
    public class CustomSearchController {
            public static String findObjectName(String recordId){
                String objectName = '';
                try{
                    String idPrefix = String.valueOf(recordId).substring(0,3);
                     
                    Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd =  Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
                     
                    for(Schema.SObjectType stype : gd.values()){
        
                        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = stype.getDescribe();
                        String prefix = r.getKeyPrefix();
                        System.debug('Prefix is ' + prefix);
                         
                        if(prefix!=null && prefix.equals(myIdPrefix)){
                            objectName = r.getName();
                            System.debug('Object Name! ' + objectName);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug(e);
                }
                return objectName;
            }
        }
```

You may run into CPU limits with this code.. if your org contains more objects.

A simple way to do this is just taking the `recordId` and just using this..inside the controller

```
  String objType = recordId.getsobjecttype();
```

Both the above solutions give what you need.

And to achieve a column format use tables and display the data as needed..

```
<div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">   
   <table> 
       <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{!v.simpleRecord.Name}</td>
                    <td>{!v.simpleRecord} </td>
                    <td>{!v.simpleRecord.CreatedDate}</td>
                    <td class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right--small  slds-truncate slds-align-left"><a href="{! $Site.siteUrlPrefix + '/detail/' + v.simpleRecord.Id}">Go to details</a> </td>
                </tr>
           
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can go with creating a wrapper class in Apex with string and Id as members and then change your controller to populate the wrapperclasslistinstead of sobject list and pass it to your component.

**Wrapper class :**

```
  public class ObjectStringWrapper {
    public  String Str;
    Public  Id Id;
}
```

Change you controller like below since you are using 3 objects in your SOSL query.

```
public class CustomSearchController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<ObjectStringWrapper> searchForIds(String searchText) {
List<List<SObject>> results = [FIND :searchText IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Id ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 10), Contact(Id), Lead(Id)]; 
List<String> ids = new List<String>();
List<ObjectStringWrapper> Reqlst = new List<ObjectStringWrapper>();
for (List<SObject> sobjs : results) {
  for (SObject sobj : sobjs) {
      
      ObjectStringWrapper data = new ObjectStringWrapper();
      data.Id = sobj.Id;
      String s = sobj.id;
      if( s.substring(0,3) == '001'){          
          data.Str = 'Account';
      }else if( s.substring(0,3) == '00D'){          
          data.Str = 'Contact';
      }
     else if( s.substring(0,3) == '00Q'){          
          data.Str = 'Lead';
      }            
    Reqlst.add(data);
  }
}
return Reqlst;
}
}
```

Since you will get the data from your apex controller, you need to change your jscontroller and populate you aura component with aura iteration in it to pass str info from wrapper class to your c:customSearchResultItem and then you will have data to display. Remember you need to have if conditions for those objects in your SOSL query.

I have tested the apex part too (asynchronous window).

```
List<ObjectStringWrapper> slist= new list<ObjectSTringWrapper>();
slist=CustomSearchController.searchForIds('Bur');
system.debug(slist);
```

[image: DEBUGLOG PIC FROM MY ASYNCHRONOUS RUN]